# angular schema-form modal....problems with $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-schema-form

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D48xcomnXdClccMnl5Jj?p=preview)

This plunker allows you to edit rows in a grid. I have created a new method based on RowEditCtrl to insert a new row but am having trouble with the validation.

When I insert a new row, the form is "pristine and valid". In the insert method, I need to call `$scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate')` which will validate the form and `form.$valid` will be false. Ideally, I would like to call this check from `ng-show` on the save button so the button does not appear until the form is ok.

The problem is, I don't understand or know how to get the schema-form `$scope` in this `RowEditCtrl` method and cannot get the form to be invalid before the user has typed anything.

```js
function RowEditCtrl($modalInstance, PersonSchema, grid, row) {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.schema = PersonSchema;
  vm.entity = angular.copy(row.entity);
  vm.form = [
    'name',
    'company',
    'phone',
    {
      'key': 'address.city',
      'title': 'City'
    },
  ];
  
  vm.save = save;
  
  function save() {
    // Copy row values over
    row.entity = angular.extend(row.entity, vm.entity);
    $modalInstance.close(row.entity);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more explanation, please?

Comment: In the documentation for schema-form it says you can validate the form at any time by calling $scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate'). In the Plunker I gave, I want to validate the form inside the RowEditCtrl function before "save()" is called, however, there is no $scope for the form here and I cannot figure out how to get the scope there or how to call "$broadcastt('schemaFormValidate')" to get the form to validate.

Comment: You could always validate the form in save method, if you pass the form as a parameter, from the HTML and implement your own validation methods.

Comment: I have actually solved the problem another way but I want to understand how I can make the $broadcast within the scope work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access `$scope` in `RowEditCtrl` by passing `$scope` into `editRow`'s `$modal.open` controller. See my fork of the original the plunkr here: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/NiwF12BLJQyD6Cku

Here are the relevant changes:

```
function editRow(grid, row) {
    $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'edit-modal.html',
      controller: ['$scope',
```

...

```
function RowEditCtrl($scope,
```

...

```
function save() {
    console.log($scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate'));
```

When I do this `console.log` of `$scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate')` within the modal's `save` function it seems to be working. Or, at least `$scope` is defined and $broadcast callable. Apologies if this does not address the question well enough, I am not familiar with `schemaFormValidate`.